# Pong Implementation using Rust SFML

Tags: rust, sfml, pong

Getting my feet wet with Game Development, and was wanting to see where I could improve in my usage of Rust as well as Game Development concepts.

```
use rand::Rng;
use sfml::graphics::{Color, Font, RectangleShape, RenderStates, RenderTarget, RenderWindow, Text, Transformable, Shape};
use sfml::system::Vector2f;
use sfml::window::{ContextSettings, Event, Key, Style};

const WINDOW_WIDTH: f32 = 800.0;
const WINDOW_HEIGHT: f32 = 600.0;

const PADDLE_MOVE_SPEED: f32 = 2.5;
const PADDLE_WIDTH: f32 = 12.0;
const PADDLE_HEIGHT: f32 = 48.0;

const BALL_MOVE_SPEED: f32 = 3.0;
const BALL_WIDTH: f32 = 8.0;
const BALL_HEIGHT: f32 = 8.0;

#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum GameState { Menu, Game, Pause }

struct Pong {
    state: GameState,
    left_score: u32,
    right_score: u32
}

impl Pong {
    fn new() -> Pong {
        Pong {
            state: GameState::Menu, 
            left_score: 0, 
            right_score: 0
        }   
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut window = RenderWindow::new(
        (WINDOW_WIDTH as u32, WINDOW_HEIGHT as u32),
        "Pong",
        Style::CLOSE,
        &ContextSettings::default(),
    );
    window.set_framerate_limit(60);

    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let font_primary = Font::from_file("res/Roboto-Medium.ttf").expect("Failed to load font file");
    let txt_color_hover = Color::rgba(255, 255, 255, 128);
    let txt_color_default = Color::rgb(255, 255, 255);

    let mut pong = Pong::new();
    let paddle_size = Vector2f::new(PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
    let mut left_paddle = RectangleShape::with_size(paddle_size);
    let mut right_paddle = RectangleShape::with_size(paddle_size);
    let mut ball = RectangleShape::with_size(Vector2f::new(BALL_WIDTH, BALL_HEIGHT));
    let mut txt_left_score = Text::new("0", &font_primary, 18);
    let mut txt_right_score = Text::new("0", &font_primary, 18);

    left_paddle.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.07, (WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.5) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2.0)));
    right_paddle.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.93, (WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.5) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2.0)));
    ball.set_position(Vector2f::new((WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.5) - (BALL_WIDTH / 2.0), (WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.5) / (BALL_HEIGHT / 2.0)));
    txt_left_score.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.25, 15.0));
    txt_right_score.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.75, 15.0));

    let mut ball_direction = Vector2f::new(rng.gen(), rng.gen());
    let mut ball_speed = BALL_MOVE_SPEED;
    
    let mut txt_title = Text::new("Pong", &font_primary, 54);
    let mut txt_play = Text::new("play", &font_primary, 22);
    let mut txt_menu_quit = Text::new("quit", &font_primary, 22);

    txt_title.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.07, WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.30));
    txt_play.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.08, WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.45));
    txt_menu_quit.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.08, WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.52));

    let mut txt_paused = Text::new("Paused", &font_primary, 54);
    let mut txt_resume = Text::new("resume", &font_primary, 22);
    let mut txt_pause_quit = Text::new("quit", &font_primary, 22);

    txt_paused.set_position(Vector2f::new(
        (WINDOW_WIDTH / 2.0) - (txt_paused.global_bounds().width / 2.0),
        WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.3 
    ));

    txt_resume.set_position(Vector2f::new(
        (WINDOW_WIDTH / 2.0) - (txt_resume.global_bounds().width / 2.0),
        WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.45 
    ));

    txt_pause_quit.set_position(Vector2f::new(
        (WINDOW_WIDTH / 2.0) - (txt_pause_quit.global_bounds().width / 2.0),
        WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.52 
    ));

    while window.is_open() {
        while let Some(event) = window.poll_event() {
            match event {
                Event::Closed => window.close(),
                Event::MouseButtonPressed { x, y, .. } => {
                    match &pong.state {
                        GameState::Menu => {
                            if txt_play.global_bounds().contains2(x as f32, y as f32) {
                                pong.state = GameState::Game;
                            } else if txt_menu_quit.global_bounds().contains2(x as f32, y as f32) {
                                window.close();
                            }
                        }
                        GameState::Pause => {
                            if txt_resume.global_bounds().contains2(x as f32, y as f32) {
                                pong.state = GameState::Game;
                            } else if txt_pause_quit.global_bounds().contains2(x as f32, y as f32) {
                                window.close();
                            }
                        }
                        _ => {}
                    }
                },
                Event::KeyPressed { code, .. } => {
                    if code == Key::Escape {
                        if pong.state == GameState::Pause {
                            pong.state = GameState::Game;
                        } else if pong.state == GameState::Game {
                            pong.state = GameState::Pause;
                        }
                    } else if code == Key::Space {
                        if pong.state == GameState::Menu {
                            pong.state = GameState::Game;
                        }
                    }
                }
                _ => ()
            }
        }

        let mouse_pos = window.mouse_position();

        match &pong.state {
            GameState::Menu => {
                if txt_play.global_bounds().contains2(mouse_pos.x as f32, mouse_pos.y as f32) {
                    txt_play.set_fill_color(txt_color_hover);
                } else {
                    txt_play.set_fill_color(txt_color_default);
                }

                if txt_menu_quit.global_bounds().contains2(mouse_pos.x as f32, mouse_pos.y as f32) {
                    txt_menu_quit.set_fill_color(txt_color_hover)
                } else {
                    txt_menu_quit.set_fill_color(txt_color_default);
                }

                window.set_active(true);
                window.clear(Color::BLACK);
                window.draw_text(&txt_title, RenderStates::default());
                window.draw_text(&txt_play, RenderStates::default());
                window.draw_text(&txt_menu_quit, RenderStates::default());
                window.display();
            }
            GameState::Game => {
                // ~~~ Left Paddle ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                if Key::S.is_pressed() {
                    if left_paddle.position().y >= 0.0 {
                        left_paddle.move_(Vector2f::new(0.0, -PADDLE_MOVE_SPEED));
                    }
                }

                if Key::X.is_pressed() {
                    if left_paddle.position().y <= (WINDOW_HEIGHT as f32 - left_paddle.global_bounds().height) {
                        left_paddle.move_(Vector2f::new(0.0, PADDLE_MOVE_SPEED));
                    }
                }
                // #########################################################################################

                // ~~~ Right Paddle ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                if Key::Up.is_pressed() {
                    if right_paddle.position().y >= 0.0 {
                        right_paddle.move_(Vector2f::new(0.0, -PADDLE_MOVE_SPEED));
                    }
                }

                if Key::Down.is_pressed() {
                    if right_paddle.position().y <= (WINDOW_HEIGHT as f32 - right_paddle.global_bounds().height) {
                        right_paddle.move_(Vector2f::new(0.0, PADDLE_MOVE_SPEED));
                    }
                }
                // #########################################################################################

                // ~~~ Ball ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                if ball.position().y <= 0.0 || ball.position().y >= (WINDOW_HEIGHT as f32 - ball.global_bounds().width) {
                    ball_direction.y *= -1.0;
                }

                if ball.position().x <= 0.0 {
                    pong.right_score += 1;
                    txt_right_score.set_string(pong.right_score.to_string().as_str());
                    left_paddle.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.07, (WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.5) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2.0)));
                    right_paddle.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.93, (WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.5) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2.0)));
                    ball.set_position(Vector2f::new((WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.5) - (BALL_WIDTH / 2.0), (WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.5) / (BALL_HEIGHT / 2.0)));
                }

                if ball.position().x >= WINDOW_WIDTH {
                    pong.left_score += 1;
                    txt_left_score.set_string(pong.left_score.to_string().as_str());
                    left_paddle.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.07, (WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.5) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2.0)));
                    right_paddle.set_position(Vector2f::new(WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.93, (WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.5) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2.0)));
                    ball.set_position(Vector2f::new((WINDOW_WIDTH * 0.5) - (BALL_WIDTH / 2.0), (WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.5) / (BALL_HEIGHT / 2.0)));
                }

                if let Some(_collision) = ball.global_bounds().intersection(&left_paddle.global_bounds()) {
                    ball_direction.x *= -1.0;
                    ball_speed += 0.1;
                }

                if let Some(_collision) = ball.global_bounds().intersection(&right_paddle.global_bounds()) {
                    ball_direction.x *= -1.0;
                    ball_speed += 0.1;
                }

                ball.move_(Vector2f::new(ball_direction.x * ball_speed, ball_direction.y * ball_speed));
                // #########################################################################################

                window.set_active(true);
                window.clear(Color::BLACK);
                window.draw_text(&txt_left_score, RenderStates::default());
                window.draw_text(&txt_right_score, RenderStates::default());
                window.draw_rectangle_shape(&left_paddle, RenderStates::default());
                window.draw_rectangle_shape(&right_paddle, RenderStates::default());
                window.draw_rectangle_shape(&ball, RenderStates::default());
                window.display();
            }
            GameState::Pause => {
                if txt_resume.global_bounds().contains2(mouse_pos.x as f32, mouse_pos.y as f32) {
                    txt_resume.set_fill_color(txt_color_hover);
                } else {
                    txt_resume.set_fill_color(txt_color_default);
                }

                if txt_pause_quit.global_bounds().contains2(mouse_pos.x as f32, mouse_pos.y as f32) {
                    txt_pause_quit.set_fill_color(txt_color_hover);
                } else {
                    txt_pause_quit.set_fill_color(txt_color_default);
                }

                window.set_active(true);
                window.clear(Color::BLACK);
                window.draw_text(&txt_paused, RenderStates::default());
                window.draw_text(&txt_resume, RenderStates::default());
                window.draw_text(&txt_pause_quit, RenderStates::default());
                window.display();
            }
        }
    }
}
```